# Stereographic projection of two-sheeted hyperboloid.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Consider $x^{2}+y^{2}-z^{2}= -1$. Now we could make a something like stereographic projection on hyperboloid. Let's call two vertices of hyperboloid $N$(north) and $S$(south). Now for any point on hyperboloid we can easy construct $(x,y,z) \to (u,v)$. And actually there is no problem to show that $\displaystyle x = \frac{2u}{1-u^2-v^2}, y = \frac{2v}{1-u^2-v^2}, z = \frac{1+u^2+v^2}{1-u^2-v^2}$.

Now we want to know the image with projection of intersection with plane $ax+by+cz+d= 0$ and $d\ne 0$. Know if we set $x,y,z$, we will get : $\displaystyle 2au+2bv+c(1+u^2+v^2)+d(1-u^2-v^2) = 0$ and we know that $c \ne 0$, so $(a,b,c,d) \to (\frac{a}{c},\frac{b}{c},1,\frac{d}{c})$, so we have : $2a'u+2b'v+(1+u^2+v^2)+d'(1-u^2-v^2)=0$, so $\displaystyle \left(u+\frac{a'}{1-d'}\right)^{2}+\left(v+\frac{b'}{1-d'}\right)^{2} = \frac{a'^2+b'^{2}+d'^{2}-1}{(1-d')^{2}}$. Now my question is : how can we show that the last one equals to arc of circle (the answer in book tell me so)

I also understand that $|\frac{a}{c}|= |a'| > 1$ or $|\frac{b}{c}|= |b'| > 1$. And if $d' = 1$, then image of projection will be a line. So if we know that $|a'|$ or $|b'|$ more than 1, then RHS will be positive and it will be

Comment: well, if the RHS of your last identity is positive then you have the [equation of a circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations) with center $(\frac{a'}{d'-1},\frac{b'}{d'-1})$ and radius $r:=\frac{\sqrt{a'^2+b'^2+d'^2-1}}{|1-d'|}$

Comment: @Masacroso ,yes  I understand that it should be circle equation.
But how can we get that it's arc of circle?

Comment: I dont follow what you mean. Any arc circle is contained in a circle.

Comment: @Masacroso yes, but it shouldn't be just a circle. The projection should be just an arc.

Comment: I'm more [used to the $d=0$ case](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2372934/35416), but I'd expect you get two arcs, one from each sheet of your two-sheeted hyperboloid, which together form a full circle except for two points. With a projective setup you'd get those two points as well.

Comment: @MvG yes, I've understood that.

Comment: Interesting information [here](https://virtualmathmuseum.org/Surface/hyperboloid2/hyperboloid2.html)